# How do I add a different class to a div when iterating through a collection on each pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is what I want the end product to look like:

```
  <div class="side-img top"><%= image_tag product.image_url(:banner_thumb).to_s %></div>
  <div class="side-img mid"><%= image_tag product.image_url(:banner_thumb).to_s %></div>
  <div class="side-img bottom"><%= image_tag product.image_url(:banner_thumb).to_s %></div>
```

Notice the 2nd class on each div changes for each `product`.

So how do I cycle through this collection and dynamically apply each of those 3 classes so I will get the above result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [cycle](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle)..

```
<% sections = %w(top middle bottom) %>
<div class="side-img <%= cycle(*sections) %>"></div>
```

..or, simply:

```
<div class="side-img <%= cycle("top", "middle", "bottom") %>"></div>
```

Comment: Ah `cycle`, that's nice. (+1)

Comment: There any benefit to using cycle over each_with_index?

Comment: @marcamillion more readable, and you can have 'named cycles'. Read up on the docs. It is more powerful than each_with_index, but either will work.

Comment: I'll update for your use now, sorry, I'm used to haml, got my wires crossed.

Comment: No worries...I got it on my end, just figured I would suggest it for others.

Comment: cycle, (+1), cant stop loving rails :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why am I seeing this in my HTML:
`<div class="side-img ["top", "middle", "bottom"]"></div>`.

It doesn't seem to be cycling.

Comment: Btw....this doesn't actually work. If I change it to: `<div class="side-img <%= cycle("top", "middle", "bottom") %>"</div>`

Then that works.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your collection is named `@products`:

```
<% sections = %w[top middle bottom] %>
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, i| %>
  <div class="side <%= sections[i] %>"><%= image_tag product.image_url(:banner_thumb).to_s %></div>
<% end %>
```

Docs on [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

Comment: I was halfway typing an answer, but @shioyama, this is more elegant and ruby'sh :D

Comment: Thanks! I use haml nowadays so my erb is a bit rusty, but I've tested this and it does what I think the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I prefer the `cycle` version. It seems particularly built for my use. i.e. the `cycle` method does.